# Estimating the zeroes and the optimal Growth of a functional :

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, gamma-function, analytic-functions

Consider the following functions :

$$F(z,s)=\frac{\sin^2(\frac{c\Gamma(z)}{z})}{z^s}$$

Here, $c$ is a real constant and $s\in[0,1]$ .

> Now we have to find the nature of following functional(w.r.t. given domain of $s$) :

> $$\int_0^\infty\frac{F(x + iy,s) − F(x − iy,s)}{e^{2πy}-1} dy $$

as $x→∞$

> Also how to analyse (for) it's zeros and local extremas  (efficiently) ?

Comment: Is $c$ real, or can it be complex?

Comment: @Paul Sinclair $c$ is real

Comment: How exactly are you defining $z^s$ off the real axis?

Comment: @Paul Sinclair $s$ belongs to unit real interval while $z$ can take complex values . I didn't really understand your question .

Comment: Before you can discuss $z^s$, you first have to specify what that means. If $s$ were integer, this is defined by repeated multiplication. But $s$ is not integer. If $z$ were real, this is defined by $e^{s\ln z}$. But $z$ is not real, and on the complex plane, there are multiple values $w$ such that $z = e^w$, so one must first choose which of those values $w$ is the one used for "$\ln z$". If you are not familiar with these facts, there are things you need to study up on before you can handle expressions like this one.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair I know what you are saying( log of complex numbers are not uni-valued), but I think it's not relevant wrt question as it is a limit question .

Comment: We are going to handle $x$ and $y$ separately on a range zero to infinity in the functional given above ( similar to functional of two real variable ) so , I don't think the above mentioned thing would be problem.

Comment: Depending on where you choose the cut, the integral over $y$ will cross it, so it is highly relevant to calculating the integral. The only question of relevance is whether or not any contribution from crossing the cut will go to zero as $x \to \infty$. Until you know that it would, you should consider it relevant.